# How can a user join a room as a spectator in Twilio Video?

Tags: video, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio Programmable Video to build a prototype chat room.

I was able to connect users into a room as participant and video and audio are attached successfully. However when a user wants to join the room as spectator, That spectator is also joined as a video participant.

How can a user connect to a room as a spectator only ?

Here is my grant code:

```
var accessToken = new AccessToken(
            Settings.TwilioAccountSid,
            Settings.TwilioVideoSid,
            Settings.TwilioVideoSecret
        );

        // Set the Identity of this token
        accessToken.identity = "spectator";

        // Grant access to Video
        var grant = new VideoGrant();
        grant.room = roomId;

        accessToken.addGrant(grant);

        res.send({token: accessToken.toJwt()});
```

Here is my connect code with the token i am returning to client:

```
Twilio.Video.connect(result.token, {name: roomId}).then(function (room) {...
```

What can i do to make a user join a room as a spectator and not as a Video Participant ?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To join a room as a spectator would mean that the user should not send audio or video. To do this, [you pass the options to `Video.connect`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.3.0/docs/global.html#connect) to say not to get audio or video streams.

```
Twilio.Video.connect(result.token, {
  name: roomId,
  video: false,
  audio: false
}).then(function(room) { ... });
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: How can I connect a user as spectator only if he doesn't have a camera?

Comment: @GuilhermeSantiago You could use `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` to find out whether a user has a video input device and then join as a spectator if they don't.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thank you

Comment: I've noticed that this approach does work, BUT in Chrome the videos don't display automatically. When I right click on the video, select Show Controls, I can then click "play" and it then displays. Firefox automatically starts all videos without having to manually start. How can it be auto-started in Chrome?

Comment: @vanarie How are you adding the participant video to the page?

Comment: Launching chrome.exe with --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required takes care of the auto-play issue. Thanks to @philnash for pointing this out.

Comment: Note that the above applies to [Google's Autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). If you are building a page in which a user is making or receiving a video call, then the user just has to interact with the page in order to allow for the videos to play immediately. You should include a user interaction to trigger the call (such as a "join the meeting" button). If you are using this for recording/streaming purposes with a virtual caller that doesn't interact with the page, then launching Chrome with the flag will help.